# Filtering object list with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, filtering

It could be a clone post but I did not find any solution for in my case. I have list of an objects:

```
export default function() {
  return [
    {name: 'Mark Teer Stegen'},
    {name: 'Nelson Semedo'},
    {name: 'Gerrard Pique'},
    {name: 'Ivan Rakitic'},
    {name: 'Sergio Busquets'},
    {name: 'Denis Suarez'},
    {name: 'Coutinho'},
    {name: 'Luis Suarez'},
    {name: 'Lionel Messi'},
    {name: 'Dembele'},
    {name: 'Malcom'}
  ]
}
```

I import it to the component, assign to the state and displaying it in the component below.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class Barca extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      players: this.props.players,
      player: '' //empty to set as an input
    }
  }

  onChange(e){
    this.setState({
      player: e.target.value
    });
    console.log(this.state.player);
  }
  renderList(){
    return this.state.players.map((player) => {
      return(
        <tr key={player.name}>
          <td>{player.name}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="col-sm-6 table-col table-responsive">
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.player}
          onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
        />
        <table className="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th className="text-center">
                FC Barcelona
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.renderList()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    players: state.reducerBarca
   };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Barca);
```

List looks like that

[image: list view]

The problem is that I would like to filter my players list by the value from input. I have done some research here and I have only found filtering in **Array**, not like I have in **Objects list**.

What I have done for now:

1. displaying the players list
2. Geting the value from the input and displaying it after every written letter
3. How to render my list by the inputted term ???

---

Thank you all people ! I have removed the players state

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      //players: this.props.players <-- Stupid thing
      player: '' //empty to set as an input
    }
  }
```

and rewrite my `renderList()` function

```
return this.props.players.filter(player =>
        player.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.player.toLowerCase())).map(searchedPlayers => {
          return(
            <tr key={searchedPlayers.name}>
              <td>{searchedPlayers.name}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })
    }
```

Comment: why are you copying the redux state to local state?

Comment: also, you're not calling `.filter` anywhere

Comment: 1. I thought that it would be easier to filter the list in React state.
2. I was trying to put `.filter` but an error ocurred then

Comment: no it makes it harder... if you just call `this.props.players.filter` you don't need any local state at all.. you don't even need to use a component class just use a function

Comment: ... and **this is an array**

Comment: setState is async, can't be read just after write - read docs ... use callback (if really needed)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
this.state.players.filter(player => player.name.includes(this.state.player))
```

And if you wanted to then map them instead of just filtering the state...

```
this.state.players.filter(player => 
player.name.includes(this.state.player)).map(searchedPlayers => {
  return(
    <tr key={searchedPlayers.name}>
      <td>{searchedPlayers.name}</td>
    </tr>
  );
})
```

Note you can also render straight from props without setting to state, (to avoid re-renders every-time the user types) by replacing

```
this.state.players
```

with

```
this.props.players
```

Comment: this answer if fine. It would be even better if mentioned that there's no reason to duplicate redux state into local state

Comment: change `INSERTUSERSEARCHHERE` to `this.state.player` - it's properly used/set

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter:

```
renderList(){
    const { player } = this.state
    const { players } = this.props
    // ignore user's typing case
    const iPlayer = player.toLowerCase()
    const filteredPlayers = players.filter(p => 
       p.name.toLowerCase().includes(iPlayer)
    )
    // now, map to the filteredPlayers
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use copy state to props, you can use `this.props.players` as well.

```
getPlayers() {
  if(this.state.player) {
    return this.state.players.filter(player => player.name.includes(this.state.player))
  } else {
    return this.state.players
  }
}
```

Then you can call `let collection = getPlayers();` and map the players to html content.